# Missing dollar inserted, cliched!

Tags: equations

I give up, what is the mistake here?!!

```
\begin{equation}
\rp = \frac{\sqrt{|s|^{2}-\pi^{2}}}{1+\bar{z}}
\end{equation}
```

I get the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.156 \rp
= \frac{\sqrt{|s|^{2}-\pi^{2}}}{1+\bar{z}}
```

I am sure I have all the brackets I need, but LaTeX doesn't seem to like it! I have already defined `r_{p}` as `\rp`. What I am looking for is to write this equation:

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete (minimial0 document tht shows the problem.. The likely cause of this error is an unmatched dollar sign earlier in the text.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry I am new to LaTeX and I don't seem to understand your comment. Do you want to me post some earlier lines of my document?

Comment: [How to create a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) should explain everything. It is a basic mechanical algorithm to follow to find the cause of a problem.

Comment: my crystal ball suggests you have defined `\rp` to be `$r_p$` which means you have `$` in math mode which is an error, just define it to be `r_p`.

Comment: What's the advantage of typing `\rp` instead of `r_p`? The number of keystrokes is the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your crystal ball was right!! It solved my problem!! You can post an answer so that I can accept it! ThAnKs a lot

Comment: @egreg But I need to type `r_{p}` everytime and I have it occurring almost every line in my document. So I thought `\rp` is a faster solution `which is without the brackets!`

Comment: You can use a macro `\rp` if you wish, but it should not have `$` in it but `\rp` is 3 characters and r_p is three characters so it doesn't save any typing really.

Comment: @ThePredator, it is, just define `\rp` to be `r_{p}` and make sure only to use `\rp` in math mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not give many hints but you have defined `\rp` by

```
\newcommand\rp{$r_{p}$}
```

which is incorrect, such a command can never be used in math mode.

You need

```
\newcommand\rp{r_{p}}
```

or simply use `r_p` without defining a command at all.

Comment: You should also suggest `\newcommand\rp{\ensuremath{r_p}}`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit -- using `\ensuremath` subtly encourages the author to not wrap a command in math indicators in text, which is generally a bad thing.  convenient, yes, sensible, no.

Comment: @PaulGaborit no, I explicitly chose not to suggest that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. Should I delete my comment to avoid suggesting that possibility? :-)